# how to detect a NFC card in windows

Tags: windows-10, nfc, rfid, mifare, proximitysensor

I am starting with RFID and NFC, I have an ET50 Zebra Tablet with windows 10 and I am trying to read and write in a MIFARE Ultralight NFC card, I am using a code that I downloaded from:
https://github.com/andijakl/ndef-nfc

But till now no luck, after researching a lot I found that Windows only can read from NFC NDEF cards, so I confirmed that this MIFARE ultralight card fits that requirement and it is correct. I was also checking windows documentation and it seems that the device is only reachable by using Proximity Device Class. I did try to implement that but again no luck detecting the card.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am using now the whole set of proximity API exposed in UWP, I had good advance on detecting the UL Card but now I am stuck on trying to write a sequence of data by using PublishBinaryMessage with messageType: NDEF:WriteTag… I know that Mifare UL card contains only some sectors avaialble for writing  4 to 16 page. but I m not sure if I have to specify that or how to do the thing.